# What does the props function do?

Tags: reactjs, function, react-redux, react-props, web-frontend

```
background-color: #${(props) => props.bg};
```

I created the front end with reactjs I got some issues in this code function

**Bellow this is the whole function**

```
left: ${(props) => props.direction === 'left' && '10px'};

<Arrow direction="left">
        <ArrowLeftOutlined />
      </Arrow>
```

Comment: your code is not complete to explain you your particular use-case, props in general [React - Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: So, you are asking what does the function do? It looks like some code within a styled css component. That should be within a template string syntax. So, that function should be basically setting up the value for background color. That's what it is.

Comment: `left: ${(props) => props.direction === 'left' && '10px'};` Please can you explain this code? I have no idea what is it?